# Matlab rotate3D and buttondownfcn incompatibility

Tags: matlab, 3d, rotation, mouseclick-event

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for all your help.

I'm currently working on a UI in matlab that includes 4 differents axes to show various info. Basicly, I have MRI data (so 3D data) that I want to show. I use 1 axe to show 3 perpendicular plane that split the data at its center (axeMain), and 3 other axes that shows the planes individually (axeX,axeY and axeZ). I have a main axe on wich I want to make rotations possible (only on the main axis system) and I want to be able to select coordinate on the 3 other axe (those with 1 plane only). I also unable translations but that is out of scope for my problem.

So basicly, I have no problem selecting my coordinates (using the buttondownfcn on my planes) on all of the 3 axes and I also have no problem using rotate3D on the mainAxe. HOWEVER, if I try to have both to work at the same time, the buttondownfcn doesn't work anymore. I don't understand why it's doing this (I have some ideas but that's about it) and I have no idea how to work around it. Basicly my code for those functions are like this :

```
    rotate3d(handles.axisMain);        
    %some other code, setting up other UI stuff

    %allow selection on the 3 static plains.
    set([handles.axeX,handles.axeY,handles.axeZ], 'buttondownfcn', @getCoord);
```

So my question is basicly : why wont those 2 functions don't work together and how to work around that problem, ideally with minimal code change?

Thanks.

EDIT : this is a print screen of my current interface. I want to be able to select coordinate using ONLY on the 3 last axes (containing only 1 plane in each of them). I also want to be able to rotate images ONLY on the first axe (the one with 3 planes). Hope this clarify.

[image: UI]

I would also like to note this : following my tests, I found that the mouse click would not raise at all if the rotate3D is activated. The problem is not in the logic I use to get the coordinates itself, but in the click event not being fired.

Also, I am aware that the event is not on the surface that I try to print. The actual code is like this :

```
    set(h, 'buttondownfcn', @getCoord);
    set(h,'HitTest','on');
```

where h is the handle of a surface and each surfaces are processed this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the exact solution!

Exploring the code for `rotate3d(hAxe,'on')` , i have found that they key line is `getuimode(hFig,'Exploration.Rotate3d')` wich returns `uitools.uimode` that contains `ButtonDownFilter` and `ModeStateData` methods.

Finally i have solved the problem in the following way:

```
rotate3d(hAxe,'on')
uiMode = getuimode(hFig,'Exploration.Rotate3d');
uiMode.ButtonDownFilter = @mycallback;
```

where:

- `hAxe` is the handle to the axes object
- `hFig` is the handle to the figure object
- `@mycallback` is the callback that lets `buttondownfcn`  and `rotate3d` works together as in the example of [Matlab's help](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rotate3d.html#zmw57dd0e724668)

So, you have to tag the object that you want to not be ignored:

```
set(hAxe,'tag','DoNotIgnore')
```

And write the callback:

```
function [flag] = mycallback(obj,event_obj)
% If the tag of the object is 'DoNotIgnore', then return true
objTag = obj.Tag;
if strcmpi(objTag,'DoNotIgnore')
    flag = true;
else
    flag = false;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
set(handles.axisMain, 'buttondownfcn', @getCoord);
```

Comment: i've updated my message to make it more clear. This solution won't help me at all sadly.