# Matlab zoom mode and buttondownfcn

Tags: matlab

I'm building a gui in `MATLAB`.  This gui has a few different `axes` objects. In one of the axes I use the `zoom` tool (activated by the figure's toolbar).  In a different axes object I've disabled zooming:

```
setAllowAxesZoom(zoom_handle,axes_handle,false)
```

...and have plotted some clickable objects:

```
text(x,y,string,'buttondownfcn',{@func_handle, value});
```

This all works great... a normal arrow cursor shows up when the mouse is in the non-zoomable plot, and no zooming occurs if I click or click-and-drag.

However! There's an inconvenient problem I'm hoping to solve.  I've discovered that when the zoom tool is activated, the `buttondownfcn` callback is not triggered by clicking on the text objects.  Right now I'm left needing to return to the toolbar to toggle zoom mode; I'd much rather just move the mouse between the different axes and have the appropriate behavior activate programmatically.

What's the best way to work around this? Is there a callback I can use when the mouse enters one of my axes?  If so I could turn on the zoom tool in that callback, and turn it off again in the corresponding "leave event" callback.  Or is there a way to propagate the mouse click event on the non-zoomable plot so it finds the appropriate callback to trigger?  Or some other possibility I'm not considering?

---

Edit: I got this to work. I've posted a solution, but would be interested in other solutions too that may work better in other scenarios, are more robust, etc.

Comment: have a look at the `hittest` property, maybe it's deactivated when zoom is activated. And then also the `buttondownfcn` would be disabled.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for the idea; it turns out the `hittest` property remains `on` even in zoom mode.  I've added a working solution to the problem as an answer, if you're curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked something together that works well for my situation; if you wanted it to be more generic and robust you could start similarly but get fancier with various tests about which `axes` a clicked object was a child of, for example, and whether there was in fact a callback installed, whether it has extra arguments, etc.

Anyway, for my specific case, the objects I care about clicking on are `text` objects, and *every* text object has a callback installed that takes *exactly one extra parameter*.

Here is the code allows me to interact with these text objects while the zoom tool is enabled:

```
function result = zoomtest(handle,eventdata)
    result=false;
    if strcmp(get(handle,'type'),'text')
        callback=get(handle,'buttondownfcn');
        callback{1}(handle,eventdata,callback{2})
    end
end

set(zoom_handle,'buttondownfilter',@zoomtest)
```

The nice thing is, this doesn't interfere with the zoom tool working as usual, nor does it change the behavior of anything if the zoom tool isn't active.

Comment: While my solution here did solve the problem, I'm going to leave the question "unanswered" for now in case anyone comes up with a better/cleaner/more robust solution!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but you can control the `State` of the zoom tool. So you could turn it on and off programatically, without returning the mouse to the toolbar. You can use `overobj` to test if you're over an `axes`.

Answer (score -2):

I have post a solution to a related question, that let you have the rotation tool works together with `buttondownfcn` ... with the zoom tools is the same philosophy:

Question / Answer to  [rotate3D and buttondownfcn incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389569/matlab-rotate3d-and-buttondownfcn-incompatibility/37434766#37434766)

**UPDATE**

Ok, i will expand and adequate the answer to this specific case:

A good way to mantain interactivity while in zoom mode is using the `ButtonDownFilter` method as described in [Matlab's help](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html?searchHighlight=zoom#zmw57dd0e933274):

```
function demo
% Allow a line to have its own 'ButtonDownFcn' callback.
hLine = plot(rand(1,10));
hLine.ButtonDownFcn = 'disp(''This executes'')';
hLine.Tag = 'DoNotIgnore';
h = zoom;
h.ButtonDownFilter = @mycallback;
h.Enable = 'on';
% mouse click on the line
%
function [flag] = mycallback(obj,event_obj)
% If the tag of the object is 'DoNotIgnore', then return true.
objTag = obj.Tag;
if strcmpi(objTag,'DoNotIgnore')
   flag = true;
else
   flag = false;
end
```

In your case the code shoud be something like:

```
function demo2
%
% Allow a text element to have its own 'ButtonDownFcn' callback.
% And taging it for interaction
text(x,y,string,'buttondownfcn',{@func_handle, value}, 'tag', 'DoNotIgnore');
%
h = zoom;
h.ButtonDownFilter = @mycallback;
h.Enable = 'on';
%
% mouse click on the text element
%
function [flag] = mycallback(obj,event_obj)
% If the tag of the object is 'DoNotIgnore', then return true.
objTag = obj.Tag;
if strcmpi(objTag,'DoNotIgnore')
   flag = true;
else
   flag = false;
end
```